# What are the new features in Java 8?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, language-features

What are the new features in Java 8?

I know there are new features like `Iterable::forEach` and streams but is there anything new in multithreading or concurrency?

Comment: Broad discussion topics are not appropriate to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

New features in java 8
1. Lambda expressions
2. Streams, Predicates, filters
3. Date API

All above are the major features introduced in java 8 . You can also go for release notes for more insight. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-relnotes-2226341.html